# Composite CHtml::listData value

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I want to post group value in a drop down. How do i concate `id` and group (`type`) in value field?

`CHtml::listData($eventLocationByUser, 'id', 'caption', 'type');`

I have tried:

`CHtml::listData($eventLocationByUser, 'id'.'type', 'caption', 'type');`

but returning empty value.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812062

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the value field accepts an anonymous function you can do it like this:

```
CHtml::listData( 
    $eventLocationByUser, 
    'id', 
    function($loc){ return $loc->id . " " . $loc->type; }
);
```

[And here is the example from the docs.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#listData-detail)

---

One alternative way could be to add another field to your model (lets say $idtype for example), and every time you create or save a record you update this field as well (using a behavior perhaps?) And then you can use:

```
CHtml::listData( $eventLocationByUser, 'id', 'idtype' });
```

It could potentially move business logic from your view to your model, but only you can decide if it's worth the hassle.

Comment: The anonymous function only works from version **1.1.13**. For anything before that you can use the model's `afterFind()` to set a new variable to the combination of `id` and `type`